# Upload photo to FTP via mail from iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, upload, ftp, web-applications

I'm building a web-application where users can upload their images. What I know is that it's "impossible" to do a file upload from an iPhone. Is it possible to achieve the same thing by letting the users e-mail their images to an adress on the same domain and the upload from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not impossible, but you will need to write some code to do so and get it deployed on the app store.  If you google for something like iphone http fille upload you'll come across loads of code examples.

It's quite possible there is already an app to upload to arbitrary web hosts, I've never looked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go with an MMS online supplier with an api? and then get the image from the api.

http://www.routomessaging.com/sms/sweden.php

If not then you could probably do what you want with an open mail client and some rules, or you could build a simple mailserver from one of the libraries on the web, should not be too hard...